# Test for convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty(\ln n)^p$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

What test do you suggest for testing the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty(\ln n)^p$ when $p<0$? I have (I hope I did it correctly) already tested the convergence for $p\ge0$ using the ratio test in this way $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left|\left(\frac{\ln (n+1)}{\ln n}\right)^p\right|=+\infty\ge1.\qquad(1)$$ The limit superior is greater or equal than 1 and for this reason the series diverges when $p\ge0$.

Thank you for your help.

*Edit*

I was wrong in (1). If $p>0$ the series diverges because $(\ln n)^p$ does not converge to zero. The question remains the same. How do I study the case $p<0$?

Comment: What makes you think this limit is $\infty$?

Comment: Yes you're right, it does not tend to infinity! I will edit the question.

Comment: @TooOld So how can I do to test the convergence when $p<0$? Can you give me a hint?

Comment: See the answer below by barto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative would be by showing that $\displaystyle\sum_{n>2}(\ln n)^p\gg\sum_{n>2}\frac1n$.

To see why, note that $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{n}{(\ln n)^{-p}}\overset{(t=\ln n)}{=}\lim_{t\to+\infty}\frac{e^t}{t^{-p}}=+\infty,$$
which implies $n\cdot(\ln n)^p>1$ for $n$ large enough.

Since $\displaystyle\sum_{n>2}\frac1n$ diverges, so does $\displaystyle\sum_{n>2}(\ln n)^p$.

Comment: Always remember: $\ln x$ is nothing compared to $x$, which is again nothing compared to $e^x$.

Comment: I can't understand. Can you be more explicit in explaining me the convergence test for $p<0$ please?

Comment: Interestingly, $\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty} \ln(k)^{-k}$ _does_ nonetheless converge (to something around $3.2426$). I wonder what the closed form is...

Comment: @Charlie, it's by comparison. He shows that eventually, the individual terms of the series become larger than the corresponding terms in the divergent series $\sum {1\over{n}}$.

Comment: @Charlie: What I essentially do is comparing the series $\sum(\ln n)^{p}$ to the harmonic series $\sum\frac1n$. It is well known that the harmonic series diverges. If we can show that every term of the series $\sum(\ln n)^{p}$ is bigger that the corresponding term $\frac1n$ in the harmonic series, from a certain index, then certainly the series $\sum(\ln n)^{p}$ will diverge too.

Comment: To show that $(\ln n)^{p}>\frac1n$ for all $n>\delta$, I use a certain limit. Since that particular limit is $+\infty$, we know that $\frac n{(\ln n)^{-p}}>1(=\epsilon)$ for every $n>\delta$. Hence $(\ln n)^{p}>\frac1n$ if $n>\delta$.

Comment: @G.H.Faust We are analyzing the case $p<0$. So we need to show that from some $n>N$ the terms $1/(\ln x)^p>1/x$. How do we end up with the limit you use in your answer?

Comment: Evaluating this limit is perhaps an unusual step. Nonetheless it is a useful technique that can often be applied. The principle is the following: Suppose $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are positive sequences, and $\lim_n\frac{a_n}{b_n}\in]0,+\infty]$. Then we have: if $\sum b_n$ diverges, then $\sum a_n$ diverges too. (The notation $]0,+\infty]$ means we include $+\infty$ as a valid limit too.) Applying this to $a_n=(\ln n)^p$ and $b_n=\frac1n$, we can conclude that $\sum a_n=\sum(\ln n)^p$ diverges. Note that this is in fact an extension on the Limit Comparison Test.

Comment: Ok, I'm almost done. My last question is: how can you evaluate the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\ln n)^p$?

Comment: As in my answer, by substituting $n=\exp(t)$. (In fact I temporarily consider $n$ as a real variable there.) For the resulting limit we have $$\lim_{t\to+\infty}\frac{e^t}{t^{-p}}=\lim_{t\to+\infty}e^t=+\infty$$ by applying l'Hopital's rule enough times.