# Convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac {1}{(\log n )^3}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Test Convergence of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac {1}{(\log n )^3}$

**Attempt:** I haven't been able to find a suitable comparator for $\dfrac {1}{(\log n )^3}$ . The integration test also seems tedious.

Please guide me on how to move forward.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: For some sufficiently large $n$ one has : 

$$
n\gt(\log n)^3,
$$

hence 

$$
\dfrac1n\lt\dfrac1{(\log n)^3}.
$$

Comment: More general case: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/649933/

Comment: @Wanderer When I first saw the series, I immediately thought of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$, so I tried to find whether $\frac1n\lt\frac1{(\log n)^3}$ holds. But with $n^2\lt(\log n)^3$ we will most probably get nothing since $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$ converges.

Comment: @user201168 Thank you very much!

Comment: @Wanderer You're welcome.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thank you for the link. Got it :)

Comment: Typo: It should be $n^2\gt(\log n)^3$ in [my second comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115566/convergence-of-sum-n-2-infty-dfrac-1-log-n-3?noredirect=1#comment2275531_1115566).

Comment: @Wanderer: You're welcome.  I found it using the following: https://mathindex.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $\log x<x^{1/4}$ for large $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $f(n):=\frac{1}{\log^{3}(n)}>0$ $\forall n\geq2$ so we will be able to use the comparison test. Furthermore, $\exists c\in[2,\infty)$ such that $n>\log^{3}(n)$ $\forall n>c$. Hence $\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{\log^{3}(n)}$ $\forall n>c$ and as we know that $\sum\limits_{n=c}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent, by the comparison test $\sum_\limits{n=c}^{\infty}f(n)$ must diverge too. Then, $\sum_\limits{n=2}^{\infty}f(n)$ diverges.

Answer (score 1):

In general, we have this $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac {1}{(\ln n )^k}$, where  $k\in\Bbb Z.$ To see this, we know $\ln (x^a)=a\ln(x)$ and $\ln (x^a)<x^a$. So, $a \ln(x)<x^a.$ Then, $$\frac{1}{\ln x}>\frac{a}{x^a}$$, put $x=n^k$. So, $$\frac{1}{\ln^k n}>\frac{a}{n^{ka}},$$ since $a$ is arbitrary, let $a=\frac{1}{k}$. We have  $$\frac{1}{\ln^k n}>\frac{1}{k n},$$ by using the comparsiion test
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac {1}{(k n)}$ is divergent. Then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac {1}{(\ln n )^k}$ is divergent as needed.